# Java Package structure and conflicts

Tags: java, spring, package

I have two project structures :

1. com.in.package
2. com.us.package

In the 2nd package, I'm using a dependency(package-core) that is defined in com.in.package!
while I was trying to run 2nd project, it was giving me some bean creation errors related to (package-core).

then I added scanBasePackages(com.in.package, com.us.package) and it was working fine.

My questions are :

suppose I created a new project with a com.harsh.package, and there is no other project on my machine.
then will it perform scanBasePackage(com.in.package) and search com.in.package?
how did the package organized in the machine?
can I say that com.in.package is a dependency on com.us.package?

Comment: No it won't. It will only scan the package (and subpackages) of the package it is defined in without further configuration.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum for the quick reply.
what I'm thinking is : 
if the package structure is like com.in.package and com.us.package then "in.package" and "us.package" are inside com package only!

if I give the structure like com.in.package and mock.us.package, then we can't perform scanning, right ?

Comment: If you specify it as a basepakcage of component scan you can just scan it.